# Wolfram alpha plot under restrictions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

I want to plot a function (f(x,y)=x^2+3y^2 under the restriction 4x+3y<=12;
Wolfram Alpha suggests a function on the help pages - 
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html

However, copying their example

Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 2 < x^2 + y^2 < 9]]

into my WA input line leads to nothing - (Try the following:
    Use different phrasing or notations
    Enter whole words instead of abbreviations etc)

so I´m pretty lost ...
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: perhaps you are confused thinking wolfram alpha accepts wolfram language input. They are quite different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [method](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot3D%5B%7Br*Cos%5Btheta%5D%2Cr*Sin%5Btheta%5D%2C%20%28r*Cos%5Btheta%5D%29%5E2-%28r*Sin%5Btheta%5D%29%5E2%7D%2C%20%7Br%2C%20Sqrt%5B2%5D%2C%203%7D%2C%20%7Btheta%2C%200%2C%202%20Pi%7D%5D)

which is

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r*Cos[theta], r*Sin[theta], (r*Cos[theta])^2-(r* Sin[theta])^2},
  {r, Sqrt[2], 3}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}
]
```

which tries to get around WolframAlpha not implementing RegionFunction by translating the problem into a parametric plot and doing a polar plot. That at least accomplishes your restriction to 2 < x^2+y^2 < 9 and perhaps you can use this idea to implement your 4x+3y <= 12 restriction.